# The import org.xxx cannot be resolved

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar

I'm new to Java, so bear with me...

I have placed a jfreechart-1.5.0.jar file in a lib folder and wanted to do do some imports like this:

```
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
```

But VS Code is complaining: the import org.jfree cannot be resolved.

One thing I have to mention is, that I have created a copy of the project folder in order to try something. Because it worked, I have deleted the original folder and renamed the copy to the name of the original folder.

But now I have the problem that the imports do not work anymore, even it's the same code. I have "cleaned Java language server workspace" but it didn't help.

Is there anything else I have to do? Is the jar import pointing to a certain path / file?

Comment: is this project using maven/gradle? 
else build project put your jar in lib folder

Answer (score 0):

For Maven project, you can add a dependency by clicking the + icon next to Maven Dependencies node in project view.

[image]

If your project is an unmanaged folder without any build tools. You can manage the dependencies by clicking the + icon or the - icon on the Referenced Libraries node or the items under it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to reference the jar file to the project.
Surprisingly the first time it has been referenced automatically, the second time I had to do it manually...

[image: screenshot of VS Code setting]